# What is the name of algorithm that generates a subgraph given a subset of nodes, where direct paths between nodes are retained?

Tags: graph-theory, programming

## Problem

I have a problem that requires a Graph algorithm, which given

$G = (V, E)$ and $V' \subset V$

returns

$G' =(V', E')$ where $E' = \{ (start, end) \in (V' \times V') : directpath(G, V', start,end) \}$

where `directpath(Graph,V', node1, node2)` means that there is a path between `node1` and `node2` in `Graph` where every node in the path is in $V \setminus V' \cup {start, end}$

More informally:
Given a subset of interesting nodes, the new graph should have an edge between two interesting nodes iff there was a path between those nodes in the original graph that only traversed non interesting nodes.

A simple example would be the graph $G = (V, \{ (R, 1), (1,C), (C,2), (2, E) \})$

Given the subset $V'=\{ R, C, E \}$ the resulting graph would be $G'$ =  $(V', { (R, C), (C,E)}$ )

## Context

I already have the actual algorithm itself working, but I am fairly sure that I just reinvented something that I can't find the name of despite searching and asking around.

Also I am wondering what a reasonably efficient way to do this is, depending on the algorithmic complexity I might have to design the code that this is part of differently. My intuition would be that this should be at least doable in linear time and I could probably get my algorithm down to that, but maybe I missing something and am wrong in either direction.

The context of this is program analysis, specifically dataflow analysis.
My use case is only concerned with directed Graphs, but this is a problem that would probably also exist for undirected graphs.

## Code

```
def filter_graph(
    graph: DiGraph[T],
    subset: Iterable[T],
    self_loops=False,
) -> DiGraph[T]:
    result: DiGraph[T] = DiGraph()


    subset = set(subset)

    for node in graph.nodes():
        if node in subset:
            t = filter_search(graph, node, subset)
            for bound in t:
                if node != bound or self_loops:
                    result.add_edge(node, bound)

    return result


def filter_search(
    graph: DiGraph[T], source: T, subset: Set[T], visited=None
) -> Set[T]:
    visited = visited or set()
    visited.add(source)

    bound: Set[T] = set()
    for succ in graph.successors(source):
        if succ in subset:
            bound.add(succ)
        else:
            if not succ in visited:
                bound |= filter_search(graph, succ, subset, visited)
    return bound
```

Comment: Without the restriction that the path use only non-interesting nodes, this is *transitive closure*.

Comment: I am aware of transitive closure (found it while searching for this), but this sadly doesn't cover my use case. The information that some node can only be reached by passing through other interesting nodes is essential for what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I have gotten to this is that "kind of a special case of Tarjan’s path expression algorithm"

Relevant Citation:

Robert Endre Tarjan. 1981. Fast Algorithms for Solving Path Problems. J. ACM 28, 3 (July 1981), 594–614. DOI:https://doi.org/10.1145/322261.322273

Credit to the person who told me about this: https://twitter.com/BanjoTragedy/status/1250796978994323456